# "Intent" from Activity to Application

Tags: android, class, android-activity

I know there is no option to Intent from Activity to Application.
There is other way to trigger and move to extends Application class from extends Activity class?

I build a project on Android Studio that extends Application and then added extends Activity for the opening of the application.
now, I can't find a way to move from the Activity class to the Application class.

There is a possible way?

Comment: Ok let me understan what do you mean. You want to create class that extends from Application and Activity at the same time?

Comment: did you get a problem with the intent? problem like can't pass data or errors?

Comment: No.
I build an app and then I created activity because I wanted to add couple of things.
Now, I want to trigger a button or something so I could move to the extends application class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be misunderstanding the difference between an `Application` and an `Activity`.

There exists only one `Application` per Android App. There can be many `Activity` classes in your App.

You cannot fire an `Intent` to an `Application`. The `Application` is not a part of your interface, it is a class that can help you maintain a global state over your entire App. [Application documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html).

An `Activity` however is the main encompassing object that contains your user interface. [Activity documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Comment: Well,
My app starts from an Activity, there is no way to trigger an button to start the (extends) application class?

Comment: No, when you start your `Activity` the `Application` class is already started (and will continue to operate until your App is completely stopped).

Comment: So I need to call my methods from the Application class in the Activity class

Comment: You should probably just leave the `Application` class completely alone. There are very few reasons why you would need to touch it.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_intents_filters.htm:

> An Android ***Intent*** is an abstract description of an operation to be performed. It can be used with startActivity to launch an Activity, broadcastIntent to send it to any interested BroadcastReceiver components, and startService(Intent) or bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int) to communicate with a background Service.